# React Bootstrap MenuItem -> onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, dom-events, react-bootstrap

If I use MenuItem then onClick ignores as event.stopPropagation also ignores a event.nativeEvent.stopPropagation also preventDefault and also stopImmediatePropagation

on click page go to href link

What am I doing wrong?

```
<MenuItem
   href="#"
   onClick={(e) => {
     log(item, e);
     e.stopPropagation();
     e.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();
     this.addItem(item);
   }}
   >{item.label}</MenuItem>
```

only if I add a `href="javascript:;"` then is working, but it is a ugly hack...

Comment: use `onSelect` instead of onClick. some of  react-bootstrap components don't support onClick

Comment: i need to prevent a.href onClick is working but the event is fired and web page go to a.href

Comment: use `return false` in your onClick function then instead

Comment: As of v0.14, returning false from an event handler will no longer stop event propagation.

Comment: ok then use the 'react-native-listener` library.  if you’re using React v0.14 already, there’s a library for this:
https://github.com/erikras/react-native-listener

Comment: Tell me if it solves your problem

Comment: How the problem is solved?

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri thanks, this helps